# Point on a polygon boundary using postgis & geodjango

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I have point data and multipolygon data in tables.  How can I find points lying on multipolygon boundary using postgis and in geodjango?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with geodjango, but I can give you a PostGIS query.

```
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_Boundary(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1,0 0, -1 1, 1 1))')),
                               ST_GeomFromText(points.g))
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['POINT(1 1)', 'POINT(0 1)']) points (g)
```

The key is to use [`ST_Boundary`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html) to get the polygon's boundary and check if that contains the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use PostGIS SQL I guess:

```
SELECT points,area from points_table,area WHERE 
area_geometry && points 
AND ST_Contains(area_geometry,points)
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what the asker meant. This will find points that are contained by the polygon, and I believe excludes points on the boundary. See [`ST_Contains`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Contains.html). Additionally, I believe the && bounding box check is redundant; `ST_Contains` already does a bounding box check.

Comment: Just confirmed that ST_Contains excludes points on the boundary. Try the following query: `SELECT ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1,0 0, -1 1, 1 1))'), ST_GeomFromText(g)) FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['POINT(1 1)', 'POINT(0 1)']) t (g)`

Answer (score 0):

Use ST_Covers it contains own boundary. But be careful in that case one point can be included by many (multi)polygons.

```
SELECT ST_Covers(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1,0 0, -1 1, 1 1))'),
                               ST_GeomFromText(points.g))
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['POINT(1 1)', 'POINT(0 1)', 'POINT(0 0.5)']) points (g)
```